# schtasks /create (Have a task that runs every day and repeats every hour

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Sorry if this or similar has been asked, and I hope I'm missing something stupid and this is easy, but.  How do I make a task using the `schtasks /create` command that will start say every day at 7 and repeat every hour either indefinitely or for the duration of a day?

If I do

```
schtasks /create /tn "test" /tr "\"C:\Program Files\test.exe"" /sc HOURLY /mo 1
```

it will only trigger if the specified date and time are hit.

If I do

```
schtasks /create /tn "test" /tr "\"C:\Program Files\test.exe"" /sc DAILY /mo 1
```

it will only trigger once a day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The batch file itself can delay for 60 minutes using `timeout` and loop to the start again.  The scheduled task can launch the batch file at 7am.

Comment: Hmm that could be a hacky way to do it, but if the computer isn't turned on at 7 or is turned off after seven, it would fail to launch the batch file or relaunch the batch file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out,  Repeat Interval is essentially what I needed along with duration

Below is how to schedule something to run at 7:00 every day every 1 hour for a duration of 1 day.

```
schtasks /create /tn "test" /tr "\"test.exe"" /sc DAILY /st 07:00 /f /RI 60 /du 24:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8.1 has this example in the help.  There is an `HOURLY` switch too.

```
==> Creates a scheduled task "accountant" on the remote machine
    "ABC" to run calc.exe every five minutes from the specified
    start time to end time between the start date and end date.

    SCHTASKS /Create /S ABC /U domain\user /P password /SC MINUTE
             /MO 5 /TN accountant /TR calc.exe /ST 12:00 /ET 14:00
             /SD 06/06/2006 /ED 06/06/2006 /RU runasuser /RP userpassword
```

Comment: ooo I think I see...  however,  how would I make it so it's every day?  (not just between the start and end date)