# VBS file to run every 1 hour

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a VBS file that is runing a bat file in background(the bat file is registering the voice for 1 hour. I want to make this VBS file to run every hour so i can register the voice non stop.

My bat file is like this:

```
@echo off
mkdir "My records"
set outputpath=My records\record_%date:~-2,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.mp3
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -y -t 01:00:00 "%outputpath%"
```

And my VBS file is like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\immol\Desktop\voice recorder\record.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

So, can someone advise how to make this VBS run every hour and have recording the voice for 24/7 ? Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the task scheduler? Why using a `VBS` when all, it does is to execute the batch file?

Comment: @Stephan I think he wants to hide the console when calling the vbs with argument 0

Comment: Hello, yes i want to make it run in background and i tried task scheduler, but i think i`m doing something wrong.

Comment: @ViCez Take a look at this question => [Create a task that runs every day and repeats every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437787/schtasks-create-have-a-task-that-runs-every-day-and-repeats-every-hour)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in linux enviroment, this sounds like a cron job. Here is the wiki for cron: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Here is 
[a tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/#targetText=The%20cron%20daemon%20on%20Linux,automatically%20run%20them%20for%20you.)

Comment: the tag `batch-file` refers to the Windows command line. The Windows equivalent to a linux cron job is a scheduled task (via GUI or the `schtasks` command)

Comment: Looks like Windows environment